# JQuery javascript timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am newbie in javascript and jquery, right now i am building a simple. It returned error at the last line. Thank you for your time.
There is some more code above but seem it requires some text so cut them out

```
Countdown.prototype.reset = function()
{
    time = this.start_time.split(":");
    this.minutes = parseInt(time[0]);
    this.seconds = parseInt(time[1]);
    this.update_target();
}

Countdown.prototype.tick = function()
{
    if (this.seconds > 0 || this.minutes >0)
    {
        if (this.seconds == 0)
        {
            this.minutes= this.minutes - 1;
            this.seconds = 59
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.seconds = this.seconds -1;
        }
    }
    this.update_target();
}

Countdown.prototype.update_target = function()
{
    seconds = this.seconds;
    if (seconds < 10)
    {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    $(this.target_id).val(this.minutes + ":" + seconds)
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: That typically means the code that's executing is doing so before jQuery has been entirely loaded. Make sure to have that code executes after jQuery has been loaded by the browser and after its `ready()` function has fired.

Comment: tks a ton bro, it worked